# Android Notification Not Showing On API 26

Tags: android, notifications, kotlin, android-8.0-oreo

I recently updated my app to API 26, and notifications are no longer working, without even changing the code.

```
val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Text")
                .build()
(getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).notify(1, notification)
```

Why isn't it working? Was there some change to the API that I'm not aware of?

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: @CommonsWare `targetSdkVersion` 26, `minSdkVersion` 21, `compileSdkVersion` 26, and `buildToolsVersion` 26.0.0. I am also running this on a phone running Android O DP3.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-channels.html):

> Android O introduces notification channels to provide a unified system to help users manage notifications. **When you target Android O, you must implement one or more notification channels to display notifications to your users.** If you don't target Android O, your apps behave the same as they do on Android 7.0 when running on Android O devices.

<sub>(emphasis added)</sub>

You do not seem to be associating this `Notification` with a channel.

Comment: That fixed it. The documentation on Notification.Builder hadn't been updated yet to reflect this. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Here i post some quick solution

```
public void notification(String title, String message, Context context) { 
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int notificationId = createID();
    String channelId = "channel-id";
    String channelName = "Channel Name";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                channelId, channelName, importance);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo)//R.mipmap.ic_launcher
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 250})
            .setLights(Color.YELLOW, 500, 5000)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(context, MainAcivity.class));
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
}

public int createID() {
    Date now = new Date();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("ddHHmmss", Locale.FRENCH).format(now));
    return id;
}
```